# Struts Select tag <key,value> pair

Tags: jdbc, struts2

Using Struts2, I have to show something like

```
<select>
   <option value="1>India</option>
   <option value="2">US</option>
   <option value="3">Mexico</option>
</select>
```

Now both the values "1,2,3..." and "India, US, Mexico,..." are to be gotten from a database via a JDBC connection. How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this class:

```
class Country {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

And you recover all the `Country` objects you have in the database with JDBC:

```
List<Country> countries = CountryDAO.getAllCountries();
```

You can render this list in the jsp with `<s:select>` tag.

## Action

```
class Action extends ActionSupport {
    private List<Country> countries;
    ...
    public List<Country> getCountries() {...}
}
```

## jsp

```
<s:select label="Pets"
   list="countries"
   listKey="id"
   listValue="name"/>
```